# Which state management library should I use for angular8 application?

Tags: redux, angular8, ngrx-store, ngxs, angular-akita

i want to using state management in my angular8 application , before do it i research about state management libraries seems NGRX and NGXS and akita.

But I'm confused as to which one to choose !

NGRS most used.

NGXS are more possibilities and easy to learning.

AKITA less used and less download according to npm download history and github forked and issue but it base on object oriented and is easy to learning.

whats is your choise? Please state your reason !

Answer (score 6):

**NGRX**: functional approach, well maintain, difficult to adapt due to high boilerplate.

**AKITA**: new to community, one of good thing about akita is independent of framework can be use with VUE,REDUX.

**NGXS**: OOP approach, can easily adapt due to less boilerplate.

i am working on angular form it's birth, i started with ngrx, than i switch to ngxs due to easily adaptation.

Comment: can be use with VUE and React